# Exclude Endpoint for Flask Session Timeout

Tags: python, session, flask

I have a Flask application that is using Flask-Sessions in order to manage my sessions.

`flask.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=30)`

After 30 minutes of activity, the session will be terminated and my user will have to login again to continue use of the application.

However, I would like to exclude a specific URL Endpoint from this session timeout behavior. What I mean is, I have a constant polling that happens in my application where the web client calls a GET /status endpoint on a 30 second interval. Every 30 seconds the page asks for updated status of tasks from the server, and updates progress bars, etc.

Due to the above GET /status call constantly being reached, the user could be completely away-from-computer and the session will never timeout because the GET /status call is continuously polling.

Is there a way I can exclude this endpoint in the timeout behavior, such that calls to GET /status *DO NOT* extend the life of the current user session? If not, what would the recommended approach be in this case? I would prefer not to have to implement my own version of Session behavior in this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to options:

1. subclass [SecureCookieSessionInterface](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.sessions.SecureCookieSessionInterface) and override [should_set_cookie](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.sessions.SessionInterface.should_set_cookie) method
2. register [after_request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.after_request) handler and there remove 'Set-Cookie' header if url matches

Comment: For anyone reading this, you'll want the first solution. If Flask Sessions intends to add the Set-Cookie header, then you will be unable to remove that header in an `after_request` handler.

Comment: In second solution you would have to return new response which will be copy of original one, except this one header. In my opinion it's too much effort, but there is such possibility :)